# Using a timer to play audio samples

Tags: objective-c, audio, timer

What I want to do is play an audio sample once with this button. Right now it just loops forever until I manually pause the sample.

```
- (IBAction)sampleButtonAction:(id)sender {    


            [self.audioManager play];

}
```

So when 5 seconds have elapsed I need to make this call:

```
[self.audioManager pause];
```

I was thinking it would be simple to just create a timer that would go to 5 seconds then just repeat the process everytime I initiated the sample.

Comment: What about: 

`self.audioManager.numberOfLoops = 0;`

Comment: It's not an object of the audioManager

Comment: Ops, I was thinking about AVAudioPlayer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use `dispatch_after` which in your concrete example would look something like this:

```
double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self.audioManager pause];
    });
```

Basically what it does is, it executes the given block on the main queue with a delay of 5.0 seconds and pauses your sound in time.